# Javascript is executing on reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using a php file to create a page that allows me to manage mysql entries. The page fetches the entries from the database and lists them which I have working fine. I am trying to add a button that allows me to "accept" an entry which changes its status value to 1 from 0.

It is working fine, except when I refresh the page, it automatically is executing the javascript function which should be an onclick event. Am I missing something incredibly simple or something. I have been looking at this for 2 days now and have rewritten it several times without success as well as extensive googling to find an answer.

My button:

```
<input type='submit' name='acceptbut' id='acceptbut' value='Accept'></input>
```

I am thinking the problem has something to do with either the location.reload or something else.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setAccept() {
        <?php
            $query = "UPDATE regiments SET status=1 WHERE memberID=$mid";
            mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        ?>
        location.reload(true);
    }
    document.getElementById('acceptbut').onclick = setAccept;
</script>
```

I have also tried messing with an inline onclick but it is not working either

My confusion is why is the function running if im not actually calling it.

Comment: Using AJAX I finally have it working and updating when the button is clicked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP executes on the server every time the page is requested.  The fact that the PHP is located inside a Javascript function is not relevant.

The PHP server parses the file, finds any PHP in it, runs the PHP on the server, then sends the result to the browser.

If you want to execute some PHP only when a Javascript function is executed in the browser, then you have to make an Ajax call from the Javascript to your server and have the Ajax call request a PHP page that can then run the desired PHP and return a result (if necessary) back to the browser's Javascript.

Keep in mind that in your setup, PHP executes on the server, then the resulting page (without any PHP in it) is sent to the browser.  The browser then executes appropriate Javascript in the web page as events occur.  The only way to execute code on the server at that point is to make an Ajax call to the server.

Comment: Oooooh, that makes sense. I wouldn't have thought of that. Thank you. I just needed a direction on where to go next, because I was pulling my hair out going in circles. I figured it was something simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Client and Server side. Look at this:

```
function javascriptFunction()
{
   <?php echo date("Y");  ?>
   return true;
}
```

The above block of code gets executed in PHP. How? Each line of the above code is treated as a sequence of characters and is sent to the `cout` (standard output). The small snippet inside the `<?php...?>` gets executed by PHP and if there are any output, it also is sent to standard output. Only when the characters are sent from server to the client side (browser), the browser starts interpreting them. Which results in a code inside `<script type='text/javascript'>..</script>` to be interpreted as a JS snippet. Now, bear in mind: EVERY PHP CODE GETS EXECUTED BEFORE THERE ANY THING AS JS, CSS or HTML. PHP SEES EVERYTHING AS EITHER String, Integer/Double or Boolean (etc.).

**What you should do?**

Learn what is AJAX, and try to learn its best practices. You'll amaze at its excellence.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ill be looking into AJAX now :)